# What is the power source for the machine that grinds up zombies?

Tags: the-walking-dead

In the scene where the zombies are getting ground up, where is the power source for that machine, in the dump?

Answer (score 4):

Early on, before the events that required this power, one of Negan's lieutenants asks:

> "What's the deal, with the helipad in the back?  The solar panels?  What was this place?"

That provides one option, solar power probably charging batteries that run the machine.  Another is that it's run by some sort of gas, which, although a valuable resource, is not so rare that people stop running cars.  From the conspicuous way it was pointed out (and the fact that it was a stationary machine in a dump rather than something that needed to be moved), I suspect the solar panels were the intended source of the power.